# Sveltekit & Fleek (IPFS) import syntax problem?

Tags: javascript, import, ipfs, sveltekit

I have managed to use [fleek](https://github.com/FleekHQ/fleek-storage-js) to update IPFS via straight javascript. I am now trying to add this functionality to a clean install of a svelteKit app. I think I am having trouble with the syntax around imports, but am not sure what I am doing wrong. When I click the button on the index.svelte I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    uploadIPFS upload.js:3
    listen index.mjs:412..........(I truncated the error here)
```

### A few thoughts

I am wondering if it could be working in javascript because it is being called in node (running on the server) but running on the client in svelte?

### More Details

The index.svelte file looks like this

```
<script>
    import {uploadIPFS} from '../IPFS/upload'
</script>

<button on:click={uploadIPFS}>
    upload to ipfs
</button>
```

the upload.js file looks like this

```
export const uploadIPFS = () => {
  const fleek = require('@fleekhq/fleek-storage-js');   
    const apiKey = 'cZsQh9XV5+6Nd1+Bou4OuA==';
    const apiSecret = '';
    const data = 'pauls test load';
    const testFunctionUpload = async (data) => {
        const date = new Date();
        const timestamp = date.getTime();

        const input = {
            apiKey,
            apiSecret,
            key: `file-${timestamp}`,
            data
        };

        try {
            const result = await fleek.upload(input);
            console.log(result);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error', e);
        }
    };

    testFunctionUpload(data);
};
```

I have also tried using the other import syntax and when I do I get the following error

```
500

global is not defined....
```

import with the other syntax is

```
import fleekStorage from '@fleekhq/fleek-storage-js';
function uploadIPFS()  {

  console.log('fleekStorage',fleekStorage)
};

export default uploadIPFS;
```

*I erased the api secret in the code above. In future I will store these in a .env file.

### Even more details (if you need them)

The file below will update IPFS and runs via the command
  `npm run upload`
That file is below. For my version that I used in svelte I simplified the file by removing all the file management and just loading a variable instead of a file (as in the example below)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const fleek = require('@fleekhq/fleek-storage-js');   
require('dotenv').config()
const apiKey = process.env.FLEEK_API_KEY;
const apiSecret = process.env.FLEEK_API_SECRET;


const testFunctionUpload = async (data) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const timestamp = date.getTime();

  const input = {
    apiKey,
    apiSecret,
    key: `file-${timestamp}`,
    data,
  };

  try {
    const result = await fleek.upload(input);
    console.log(result);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('error', e);
  }
}
// File management not used a my svelte version to keep it simple
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'README.md');

fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
  if(!err) {
    testFunctionUpload(data);
  }
})
```